# How to get highly contextualized vectors for a few sentences/paragraphs with doc2vec

Tags: python-2.7, nlp, word2vec

How to get highly contextualized vectors for a few sentences? I suppose if I use a little corpus (where uniquely a few sentences are present) for training doc2vec, the trained vectors could not be well trained. So how to add context in an efficient fashion?

My initial idea is to add sentences which I'm interested in to a mass corpus (e.g. Wikipedia). Then retrieve the corresponding vectors. Nevertheless, I think this approach could be expensive because the algorithm has to consider all sentences in the corpus (e.g. millions of them, but it is probably the logic assumtion).

Thank you.

Comment: As I said, I implemented the initial idea. Resulting vectors are very useful. There is still the question about of if it is possible to get the same vector quality without training `doc2vec` for all sentences of the corpus, but only for some of them we are interested in. It would be possible using pretrained `word2vec` word vectors?